# How to get listitems in JSONObject?

Tags: json, kotlin

my JSON is supposed to look like this.

```kotlin
{"zip":123, "people":[{"firstname":"Thomas", "lastname":"Tatum"},
{"firstname":"Drew", "lastname":"Uncle"}]}
```

(`I am using import org.json.JSONObject`)

I have a MutableList, in the List are Person (it’s a data class with firstname and lastname).
But I don’t know how to get my list items in a JSONObject to fit in json (see below).

```
val json = JSONObject(
            mapOf(
                "zip" to 123,
                "people" to //I don't know how to get my values here
            )
        )
```

Maybe someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this

```
import org.json.JSONObject

data class Person(val firstname: String, val lastname: String)

fun main() {
    val people = arrayOf(Person("Thomas", "Tatum"), Person("Drew", "Uncle")) //also works for Lists, doesn't need to be an array
    val json = JSONObject(
        mapOf(
            "zip" to 123,
            "people" to people,
        )
    )
    println(json)
    //prints: {"zip":123,"people":[{"firstname":"Thomas","lastname":"Tatum"},{"firstname":"Drew","lastname":"Uncle"}]}
}
```

Comment: @JochenMiddleboroguh actually it can be much easier. apparantly you can just pass the list of Person there. see my Edit. I guess it's smart enough to turn a data class into a map by itself

Comment: That's right. Perfect!